# Compiling PJSUA for video calling android

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

Hello I am trying to compile PJSUA with video feature. As per [docs](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#pjsua) I have configured my Android.mk file.

```
# Path to SWIG
MY_SWIG     := /home/neosoft/PJSIPTOOLS/swig-3.0.7/swig
MY_MODULE_PATH  := $(PJDIR)/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-$(TARGET_NAME)
MY_MODULES      := $(MY_MODULE_PATH)/pjsua_app.o \
           $(MY_MODULE_PATH)/pjsua_app_cli.o \
           $(MY_MODULE_PATH)/pjsua_app_common.o \
           $(MY_MODULE_PATH)/pjsua_app_config.o \
           $(MY_MODULE_PATH)/pjsua_app_legacy.o
```

After running ndk-build command as per docs I am getting following error.

ndk-build command : `./ndk-build -C /home/neosoft/PJSUA/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/android/`

Error:

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: pjsua <= pjsua_wrap.cpp
jni/pjsua_wrap.cpp: In member function 'virtual void SwigDirector_PjsuaAppCallback::onStarted(const char*)':
jni/pjsua_wrap.cpp:710:52: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
       throw Swig::DirectorException(jenv, swigerror);
                                                    ^
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/pjsua/pjsua_wrap.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/neosoft/PJSUA/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/android'
```

any suggestion how to resolve this?

Comment: Resolved error by adding LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += rtti
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions flags to Android.mk

Comment: I ran into another issue of  ../src/pjsua/pjsua_app_legacy.c:1660: error: undefined reference to 'pjsua_dump' now :-(

Comment: it may occur for java version mismatch with swig..check it too.

Comment: @riazhasan can you please help me with these undefined reference errors?